# How to scale a triangle with rectangle content in css?

Tags: html, css

I have created a triangle with a border and a coloured background. However it is attached to a rectangle with some content and i can't figure out how to scale the triangle with it.

I have used a pseudo element and put a triangle on top of another triangle to create the border, so not sure if this way is possible to scale with.

[My problem is the triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6wcZ.png)

HTML:

```
                 <div class="skipcontent">
                
                    <i class="bi bi-skip-end-circle" style="font-size:36px;"></i>
                    <p class="alertcontent">content can span onto 2 lines. content can span onto 2 lines. content can span onto 2 lines. content can span onto 2 lines. </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 700px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #D9F1FF;
  border: 1px solid #7197C9;
  position: relative;
  color: #000000;
  font-size:15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}


/* this CS forms the triangles */
.container:after,
.container:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    
}


/* this border color controls the color of the triangle (what looks like the fill of the triangle) */
.container:after {
    top: 0px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #D9F1FF;
    border-width: 26px;
    margin-left:-2px;
}

/* this border color controlls the outside, thin border */
.container:before {
    top: 0px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #7197C9;
    border-width: 26px;
    margin-left:-1px;
}


.skipcontent {
   padding:0 0 0 20px;
   display:flex;
   align-items:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by using "**Clippy - clip-path**". But you can't add the border and border-radius on everywhere.
Reference site link - https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/
Demo Screenshot - https://prnt.sc/-J3_o3rHqlFU

```
.skipcontent {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 97% 0, 100% 28%, 97% 50%, 97% 100%, 0 100%, 0% 35%, 0 0);
}
```